# Different language string not supported textview on settext in android?

Tags: android, localization, textview

I should made and display for all different lang string getting from database its fine but textview on settext not shown.
So, this is type of string **១ ថ្ងៃ អង្គារ ពុធ** not display.
Thanks for advance.

```
String title = diffLang.getSpokenLanguage(); // here, language string get
    try {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));  // not display
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the text by getBytes? Why not set the title String exactly? Anyway, I tried both variants and your text ១ ថ្ងៃ អង្គារ ពុធ  displays normally. I think the problem is diffLang.getSpokenLanguage() returns wrong result or holder.txtTitle is not defined correctly(mb wrong view id or etc).

Comment: not its perfectly string getting when i should printed on logcat and i think so utf problem but i should not clear about what th issue and getting perfcely textview findviewbyid.

Comment: Directly settext on textview on this getting string diffLang.getSpokenLanguage(); not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lots of searched and found solution for my self

```
 protected String getConverTextUTFToNormal(String arabicValue) {
    String getConvertValue = "";
    try {
        getConvertValue = new String(arabicValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        getConvertValue = arabicValue;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(getConvertValue, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(getConvertValue).toString();
    }
}
```